# How to set full screen particles-bg in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, particles

I am having a problem regarding how to set **Particle-bg to the whole page in ReactJS**. I used lines style and it is working but it fits only for a section. If I add more content on the page Particles-bg doesn't apply to them. I want to set the background to the whole page.

This is the function that I used. `<ParticlesBg  num={50} type="lines" bg={true}/>`

If someone knows how to fix this help me.

Answer (score 0):

Particle-bg automatically applies to the whole background. when you add more components, it goes underneath that component. so you have to use something which has a transparent background.

```
return (
    <div>
        <YourComponent/>
        <ParticlesBg color="#000000" num={100} type="cobweb" bg={true} />
    </div>
);
```